# Retrieving just file name from AWS S3 in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I'm making Angular-Rails web app now. I successfully retrieve files from certain path in AWS S3.

Let's say I call below function

```
@files = bucket.objects.with_prefix('pdf/folder/')

    @files.each(:limit => 20) do |file|
        puts file.key
    end
```

`file.key` prints `pdf/folder/file1.pdf`, `pdf/folder.file2.pdf`, etc.

I do not want the whole path but just name of files like `file1.pdf`, `file2.pdf`, etc.

Is regex the only way or is there a API call for this in AWS S3? I was reading the doc and could not find related API function.

Answer (score 5):

The call you want is probably [`File#basename`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.1/File.html#method-c-basename):

```
puts File.basename(file.key)
```